# Ionic 4 - Fingerprint AIO build fails

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I installed the plugin using the documentation from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio, removed older fingerprint plugins, such as Android Fingerprint Auth and Touch Id. Tried running command to create a local build, and it fails only for Android.

**Environment:**

```
ionic 4.12.0
cordova 8.1.2
```

**Java:**
[image]

**Plugin version**

```
"cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^3.0.1"
"@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio":" ^5.22.0"
```

**Error:**
[image]

I'm not really sure on how to proceed or fix this.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is your error:

```
use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions
```

**1. The plugin requires Java 8** (yours is indeed 8).

for other whom are stuck, check your java version.

`java -version` in cli

and install java 8.

**2. Some of your plugins may be outdated and uses Java 7**

I would recommend deleting the following folders:

*node_modules, platforms, plugins*

and run:

```
npm install

ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: We found out that one of our dependencies was actually using JAVA 7, so we updated it and this error stopped showing up. Thanks for the answer though, this will probably help a lot of people.